# CPU/Memory issues with Java in Parallels

Tags: java, parallels, tws

I use Interactive Brokers TWS in Parallels on a Mac with 8gig memory.  Parallels uses 4gig.  Everything has been fine for 3 years.  In the last month, something has changed and I am not able to run more than one other program alongside TWS.  When I look at Task Manager, I see the following stats:

Physical Memory:

Total      2815

Cached     1237

Available  1224

Free       0

Kernel Memory:

Paged      264

Nonpaged    40

System

Handles            16721

Threads             693

Processes             51

Up Time       0:13:48:19

Commit/MB      2109/5629

and the CPU Usage is 100%.  When I look at the Processes tab, javaw.exe is taking up 98%.

I don't know if this is related, but TWS flashes the View menu item very fast.  You can see it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4anpepfdg4rqu9/Flash.mov?dl=0

I haven't made any changes to my system, so I don't know what has happened to cause this.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed Karabiner (formerlrly KeyremapForMacbook) possibly?  I also got weird keyboard problems after installing Parallells so I skipped it. May I ask why you don't use TWS for OS X instead of the Windows version?

Comment: I use TWS for Parallels so I can use TWS along side Trade Ideas.  I figured out the problem.  My VM had a virus that started with boot-up.  This caused all the problems (including the blinking menu item).  I re-installed Windows and reloaded all the software and now everything works great.

Comment: Aha. Reinstalling Windows because of viruses, I have heard that one before!

Answer (score 0):

In previous times of funky TWS/javaw behavior, whipping out the current java cache [Configure Java/Settings/Temporary Internet Files] has been recommended to me by IB, to good effect. Your description (minor constituent/platform changes: aberrant behavior) makes this sound applicable.